# Don't working authentication in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-routing, laravel-5

Don't working authentication. I create authentication manually.
My `AdminController`:

```
class AdminController extends Controller
{

    public function signin() {
        return view('admin.signin');
    }

    public function index(Request $request) {

        dd(Auth::check());
        if (Auth::check())
            return view('admin.index.index', ['login' => Auth::user()->name]);
        else
            return redirect()->action('AdminController@signin');
    }

    public function login() {
        $data = Input::all();

        if (Auth::attempt(['name' => $data['login'], 'password' => $data['password']])) {
            return redirect()->intended('/admin');
        } else {
            return redirect()->intended('/admin/signin');
        }
    }

    public function logout() {
        if (Auth::logout() ) {
            return Redirect::to('/admin');
        }
    }
}
```

My `routes.php` file:

```
  //GET
  Route::get('/', 'IndexController@index');
  Route::get('/admin/signin', 'AdminController@signin');
  Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index');
  Route::get('/admin/logout', 'AdminController@logout');

  //POST
  Route::post('/admin/auth', 'AdminController@login');
```

`dd(Auth::check());` returned `false`

What I doing wrong?

Comment: Does the manual not say that `dd()` dumps a variable and ends execution of the script?

Comment: do your routes have the 'web' middleware group applied ?

Comment: @RiggsFolly with dd() i just check returned value, without dd() page redirecting to signin action. And authentication don't working.

Comment: No, my web middleware not contain the routes, because with this, cause the error with `TokenMismatchException`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Laravel 5.2 you need to define routes using `web` middleware to make sessions work, so your `routes.php` file should look like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
  //GET
  Route::get('/', 'IndexController@index');
  Route::get('/admin/signin', 'AdminController@signin');
  Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index');
  Route::get('/admin/logout', 'AdminController@logout');

  //POST
  Route::post('/admin/auth', 'AdminController@login');
});
```

Comment: I did as you said, but the error is output: `TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67:`

Comment: When do you have this error. Just when you open fresh page with form and try to log in? If you had it open for a long time it's normal you are getting this error

Comment: Thanks your answer helped me, but now experience another problem with `Auth::logout()` this method returned `null`